# TeX.sx blog feedback

Tags: discussion, blog

Now that there is a [blog started](http://tex.blogoverflow.com/), a key question is getting some feedback. I've written both the ['hello world' post](http://tex.blogoverflow.com/2011/07/welcome-to-the-tex-sx-blog/) and something a [bit more substantial](http://tex.blogoverflow.com/2011/07/a-regular-answer-the-unanswered-slot/). What to write for the blog depends on the community as a whole. So feedback on the content would be great. I guess one answer per feedback 'concept' would be best.

Comment: We should do something for the "official opening" of the blog on our birthday next week...

Comment: I keep trying to upvote your blog post! ARG!

Comment: Could you add a link to the **[Blog Editor (Chat) Room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/884/tex-blog-editor-room)**, so both are cross referenced.

Comment: @Seamus: This happens to me now when I go to `comp.text.tex`! :-D

Answer (score 7):

The design of the TeX.SX blog has been updated by Jin to match the main site:

[image: TeX blog layout]

Answer (score 5):

i've finally unearthed my bibliography of items on "mathematical typography".
i seem to remember that i once made a rash promise to post it as a blog entry when i found it.
(it's certainly not appropriate even for the *answer* to a regular question.)

what i need now is a lesson on how to format it -- same markup as used for the q&a, or
something else? -- and assistance in actually getting it posted, with the ability to
edit it (e.g., add or change items) as i come across new material.

any support for doing this, or objections?  any volunteers for checking the content before
it's ready to "go live"?

Answer (score 3):

It would be great to have the StackExchange login automatically transfered to the blog. Or at least to use an existing wordpress.com login.

Comment: Probably one for the StackExchange team

Comment: I don't think the login data can be synchronized between the two systems.

Answer (score 3):

I know that an "official" link has to wait for the "official" launch of the blog, but it does seem a bit daft that there are *no* links from the main site.  I seem to recall that it is possible for a moderator to put a banner up on the main site for a couple of days.  Maybe it would be worth doing that; perhaps after a couple of posts have gone up.

Comment: Perhaps for our 'first birthday'?

Comment: Create a [community promotion ad](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/05/community-promotion-ads/) for the blog. (:

Comment: @Joseph: I just saw the banner. Is it on purpose that there's no link? Of course one can copy&paste, but I'd find a link a lot nicer (if possible).

Comment: @Hendrik: Hopefully sorted - getting the link right was a challenge!

Comment: @Joseph: Works fine for me now.

Comment: This has now been changed - we now have all blog links point to their respective blogs, regardless of whether or not the blog has "graduated" (i.e. gone to blog.stackexchange rather than blogoverflow). Enjoy! ♪

Comment: @Grace Note: Great!  Though I doubt that that piddly little link at the bottom of the page will _drive_ traffic to the blog ... I'm after the one at the top of the page.  When do we get that one?

Comment: You have it, actually! ♪ For unregistered users, it will always be available, and for registered users, **it will be available for 24 hours after every new post**. As such, as long as your blog is nicely active, you'll have a persistent link. I also recommend a [Community Ad](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/community-promotion-ads-1h-2011) for your blog, as this can increase the visibility even further. ♪

Comment: @Grace Note: That's great ♯.  I hadn't seen that after the previous posts; I'll have to go and write another one to see it in effect ♯.  I agree with the need for a Community Ad, but sadly my design skills are seriously lacking so I'll pass that on to another♯.